# ERROR:the operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Tags: facebook, titanium

I am getting sdk problem, what I change in the code for removing error?

Please help me, I am new in titanium.

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('pumpkin.jpg');
var blob = f.read();
var data = {
        message: 'This is a pumpkin',
        picture: blob
    };
Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/photos', data, 'POST', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unkown result");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to execute example code from online doc so if you are using traditional structure then put one pic with pumpkin.jpg in resources directory because i think that file should be missing.
and be sure that you are calling after login.